# ionic 2 - Property 'dismiss' does not exist on type 'ActionSheetController'

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I am following the [doc](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/action-sheet/ActionSheetController/) trying to create Actionsheet. Not sure why getting the error message `Property 'dismiss' does not exist on type 'ActionSheetController'` on the `dismiss()` and `Cannot find name someAsyncOperation` for the `someAsyncOperation()`.

Did I miss anything?

```
import { ActionSheetController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, ModalController, ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';
constructor(
 public viewCtrl: ViewController,
 public navCtrl: NavController, 
 public actionSheetCtrl: ActionSheetController,
 public modalCtrl: ModalController,
 public navParams: NavParams,
) {}

openActSheet(){

    let actionSheet = this.actionSheetCtrl.create({

    title:"Type",
    buttons:[
    {
    text: 'Hour',
    handler: () => {

            let navTransition = this.actionSheetCtrl.dismiss();

            someAsyncOperation().then(() => {
                    console.log("text");
            })


            navTransition.then(() => {

                this.navCtrl.pop();

            }); 
    }
    },
{
 text: 'Day',
 handler: function(){
 console.log("Day Clicked");
 }
},
{
 text: 'Week',
 handler: function(){
 console.log("Week Clicked");
 }
},
{
 text: 'Month',
 handler: function(){
 console.log("Month Clicked");
 }
}
]
 });
 actionSheet.present();
}
```

Comment: where is someAsyncOperation defined?

Comment: Hi, I did not define It. Do I need to define the function before using it?! Sorry first time using the ActionSheet not familiar with it.

Comment: It is a custom javascript function..yes.. you need to define what action needs to happen. The docs just has a sample demo..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ActionSheetController](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/action-sheet/ActionSheetController/) *does not have `dismiss()` function.* It is available in `actionsheet` Object.

Try:

```
openActSheet(){

    let actionSheet = this.actionSheetCtrl.create({

    title:"Type",
    buttons:[
    {
    text: 'Hour',
    handler: () => {

            let navTransition = actionSheet.dismiss(); //here
   //....
```